# Automating Flipkart Application using selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-applications, testng

My scenario is to search anyone brand laptop and i need to select the highest price in the current page without sorting.

```
@BeforeClass
public void launchBrowser()
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com");
}

  @Test(priority = 0)
  public void searchComputers() throws InterruptedException
  { 
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@title='Search for Products, Brands and More']")));
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='O8ZS_U']/input")).sendKeys("laptops");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='O8ZS_U']/input")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@title='HP']//div[@class='_1p7h2j']")));
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@title='HP']//div[@class='_1p7h2j']")).click();
}

 @Test(priority = 1)
 public void searchHPComputers() throws InterruptedException
 {
   Thread.sleep(2000);
  WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
  wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[text()='Newest First']")));
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  List<WebElement> element =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK']"));
  for(WebElement web : element)
  {
     String amount =  web.getText();
     int length = amount.length();
     String price = amount.substring(1, length);
     System.out.println("Amount : "+ price);
     Thread.sleep(1000);
  }

}


 @AfterClass
 public void closeBrowser() throws InterruptedException
 {
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  driver.close();
  driver.quit();
 }
```

I have printed all the price list in the current page in eclipse console.
    But I have no idea how to click on the highest price laptop.
Kindly help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to click on the search with highest price you need to perform following 2 things:

**#1** Comment following lines:

```
  JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
```

**#2** replace `searchHPComputers()` method body with following code

```
      Thread.sleep(5000);
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[text()='Price -- High to Low']")).click();

      Thread.sleep(5000);
      List<WebElement> element =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK']"));

      element.get(0).click();
```

and voila!!

**UPDATE**

```
@Test(priority = 1)
public void searchHPComputers() throws InterruptedException
{

    Thread.sleep(2000);
    WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
    wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[text()='Newest First']")));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    List<WebElement> element =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK']"));
    List<WebElement> elementLink = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='_3wU53n']"));

    int largestPrice =0, elementIndex =0, i=0;

    for(WebElement web : element)
    {
        String amount =  web.getText();
        int length = amount.length();
        String price = amount.substring(1, length);
        price = price.replaceAll(",", "");
        int priceInt = Integer.parseInt(price);
        System.out.println("Amount : "+ priceInt);
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        if(priceInt > largestPrice) {

            largestPrice = priceInt;

            elementIndex = i;
        }

        i++;
    }


    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elementLink.get(elementIndex-1));

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elementLink.get(elementIndex)));

    elementLink.get(elementIndex).click();
}
```

Comment: I need to select the highest price laptop in the current page without sorting.